# Gmail API python connection works on Windows but not Mac

Tags: python, google-api

I have the following Python code to connect to my a Google spreadsheet I own. The API credential is stored on a Dropbox folder which is synchronized to both my Windows machine and my mac. I have checked that the URLs for the folder are correct for each system.

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    weight_folder = #path to Dropbox folder on my Windows machine
else:
    weight_folder = #path to Dropbox folder on my Mac


client_id = 'redacted'
client_secret = 'redacted'
height = 182

flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
storage = oauth2client.file.Storage('credentials_weight.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[oauth2client.tools.argparser]).parse_args([])
    credentials = oauth2client.tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

This works totally fine when I run it on my windows machine. When I run it on my mac however, I get the message

> Failed to start a local webserver listening on either port 8080
> or port 8090. Please check your firewall settings and locally
> running programs that may be blocking or using those ports. Falling back to --noauth_local_webserver and continuing with authorization. Go to the following link in your browser:

Following the link gives me the following message

> Error 400: invalid_request. You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

I am not very skilled with Google's APIs, but I don't understand why the app would be authorized on Windows but not authorized on mac. It feels like the error message is not accurate.

What could cause this?

Comment: last one normally meahs you are using http and not https.   Wonder if this is just an issue with the configuration of your ide on mac

Answer (score 0):

Based off the message on the link, I do think it's something related to the Google API settings. There are a couple of different possible solutions on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68764885/google-oauth-2-0-api-authentication-error-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-do) which seem relevant to your case.